# using underscorejs in a couchapp list

Tags: couchdb, requirejs, underscore.js, couchapp

I'm using couchdb 1.2.x, and I'm trying to use [`underscorejs`](http://underscorejs.org/) in a list, without success.

here is how I proceed:

```js
function(head, req) {
  var _ = require('vendor/underscore/underscore');
  log(_);
}
```

By looking at the couchdb log, I can see that `var _` is undefined. Also, underscorejs log says:

> 1.3.0 — Jan. 11, 2012
>   Removed AMD (RequireJS) support from Underscore. If you'd like to use Underscore with RequireJS, you can load it as a normal script, wrap or patch your copy, or download a forked version.

I'm not sure exactly how to proceed; any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only suggest I have is to use the drop-in replacement [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/).

Among other things if offers AMD loader support.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatly I haven't been able to use lodash as well. Here is what i've done: `var _ = require('vendor/lodash'); log(_.VERSION);`. I have also tried the various ways indicated on http://lodash.com/ without success. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message in the log states, Underscore.js is no longer formatted as an AMD module out of the box.  You have two possible solutions: shim or use an AMD-ified underscore.

**Shim:**

[Shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) will wrap underscore in the necessary AMD boilerplate and be relatively transparent to you, allowing you to use an unmodified version of _.

In your case it's easy, configure requireJS like so:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    underscore: "vendor/underscore/underscore"
  },
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    }
  }
});
```

*Note:* I also defined a path alias for underscore for convenience but it's not necessary to make the shim work.

**AMD-ify:**

An AMD-ified version of underscore (and backbone) is maintained by the author of requireJS here: https://github.com/amdjs/underscore

Comment: @rhaper
Thanks, unfortunatly It doesn't work. I think this is because couchdb has support for requirejs v1 only, but I might be wrong as I'm not very accurate on this. The AMD-ify version does not work as well (`var _ = require('vendor/underscore'); log(_);` returns undefined). Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to create a couchdb list function. Here's how I pulled in underscore. This is all in coffeescript...

In my design document I import and declare the library then pull that in from the list function:

```js
designDoc =
  ...
  lib:
    underscore: "<actual underscore code as a string>"
  ...
  list:
    listFunction: "<list function as a string, see below>"
  ...
```

In the list function itself:

```js
(head, req) ->
  _ = require 'lib/underscore'
```